# To check whether a given tree allowed duplicates is binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I know how to check whether a given tree is binary tree or not. But the problem is what if the tree contains duplicate values.

> How to check whether a tree which may contains duplicate values is a binary search tree or not 
>   The duplicate values must be on the right side of a tree/sub tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the binary search tree program when you add a check if the tree on the right is BST or not, then check if the value on the right is greater or equal to.
For instance,

```
bool BST(BinaryTree root){
 bool returnValue=false;
  if(root!=null){
    if(root.left!=null){
      if (root.left.data < root.data){
       returnValue=BST(root.left);
      }
    }
    if(root.right!=null){
       if(root.right.data >= root.data){
          returnValue=BST(root.right);
       }
   }
   return returnValue;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code has many mistakes..what if root.right is None and also see this case  in level order 2 1 2 and also  4 3 4 2 6

Comment: you right about the null check which I have edited, please note the  code above is just for reference. To explain about the check for duplicates. You can also use range to verify if it is a BST with duplicates.

Comment: You can also refer a similar discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727871/bst-with-duplicates

Comment: You are checking or comparing the child nodes only with the parent nodes. What if the leaf node is greater than the root node. LEVEL ORDER EXAMPLE-- 4 2 6 1 5 5 8