# post-order traversal binary tree right to left

Tags: search, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, traversal, postorder

I know what the output would be when we traverse a binary tree with a post order algorithm from left to right, however I am having a bit of trouble seeing what it would be when we go from right to left.
For example, would the output of a post order traversal of the following tree be "9 9 8 7 3 2 1 2 6 7"? Or would it be "9 9 7 8 3 2 1 2 6 7"? Or am I wrong in both cases? 
            7
      3           9
   2     6      8     9
 1   2        7

Comment: As introduction to your question, the proposed list `7 3 9 2 6 8 9 1 2 7` has duplicate values. Please confirm that because in a BST _"duplicates are not allowed to be inserted"_ (see that post ["BST - Inserting an equal value element"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9384858/6945651))

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tree is simple`binary tree` instead of `binary search tree` your output should be -

**9 8 9 7 6 2 1 2 3 7**

Actually you can simply use this function to get post order from right to left-

```
void post(struct Node*root){
   if(root==NULL)
     return;
   if(root->right)
     post(root->right);
   if(root->left)
     post(root->left);
   printf("%d ",root->data);
}
```

where`printf`is function to print data if you dont know C.