# Returning node value that does not exist in binary tree in O(1)

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, big-o, binary-search-tree

I need to return node value, that doesn't exist in binary search tree in `O(1)`. The tree has node values from `(1,2...M)`.

The hint was to use binary search tree and to save in every node 3 fields, that will help me.

My idea was to create a field in the root that contains all the values possible, from `(1..M)` and every time we insert node with a certain value, we check the extra field in the root and delete it if it exist.

last to return a value that does not exist in the tree all we have to do is to enter that field in the root and return any value in it.

Any idea? Am I right?

Comment: Why is this tagged as [java] and [c]?

Comment: @user2864740 NOT a particular value,just to return a random value from [1..M] that dosn't exist in the binary search tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that each node contains these three data fields:

- value: value of the node itself
- left: *smallest* value in the consecutive range to the *left* of this node
- right: *largest* value in the consecutive range to the *right* of this node

The left/right values form the bounds of the "non-gap" value range of *descendant* nodes around the node's value. To find *a* missing value, pick one of these end-values then pick the appropriate adjacent (i.e. +/-1) value.

Whenever a child node is inserted or deleted, the left/right of all *ancestors* will need to be updated - this does not change the insert/delete complexity bounds nor is it part of the "find-missing" operation. The "find-missing" operation itself has a complexity of O(1) as only the left/right of the root node (and range of all values) needs to be considered.

Consider this tree:

```
     +--- 4 ---+
     |         |
+--- 3         6 ---+
|                   |
1                   7
```

Now, start adding L<..>R values from the leaves; trivially a leaf node has the range over a single value.

```
       +--- 4 ---+
       |         |
  +--- 3         6 ---+
  |                   |
1<1>1               7<7>7
```

and added to ancestors..

```
       +--- 4 ---+
       |         |
  +- 3<3>3     5<6>7 -+
  |                   |
1<1>1               7<7>7
```

and added to ancestors..

```
       +- 3<4>4 -+
       |         |
  +- 3<3>3     6<6>7 -+
  |                   |
1<1>1               7<7>7
```

Then by looking at the root node it is known that [3, 4] is a consecutive range of values in *descendant* nodes which contains the nodes value. Two missing values are thus 2 (3-1) or 5 (4+1).

Now, adding a node..

```
       +- 3<4>7 -+
       |         |
  +- 3<3>3  +- 5<6>7 -+
  |         |         |
1<1>1     5<5>5     7<7>7
```

.. and two missing values are known to be 2 and 8 ..

```
       +----- 1<4>7 -----+
       |                 |
  +- 1<2>3 -+       +- 5<6>7 -+
  |         |       |         |
1<1>1     3<3>3   5<5>5     7<7>7
```

.. and now 0 (which may be out of range) and 8.

---

The approach of using "a field in the root that contains all the values possible" sounds like using a separate Set data-structure, which is likely missing the goal of the assignment given the hint. Furthermore, consider that a binary tree ([without duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/300935)) *is* a Set itself.